# How does the W10 News app stretch the items in the gridview?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview

I'm trying to create a gridview like in the default News app in Windows 10. As far as I know I have to set the ItemHeight an ItemWidth for the VariableSizedWrapGrid. But then it does not stretch the items to fit the full grid width, while the News app does do that as you can see in the pictures below. How do they do that? Is it a special custom control?
[image: Widescreen, 4 columns and items are quite wide]

[image: Narrowscreen, 3 small columns]

Answer (score 9):

I will just give you the concept:

```
+---------+ +---------+ +---------+ 
|  small  | |         | |         |
+---------+ |         | |         |
--- gap --- | medium  | |         |
+---------+ |         | |         |
|  small  | |         | |   big   |
+---------+ +---------+ |         |
--- gap --- --- gap --- |         |
+---------+ +---------+ |         |
|  small  | |  small  | |         |
+---------+ +---------+ +---------+
--- gap --- --- gap --- --- gap ---
```

So we only have 3 different boxes for presentation with a known height. 
The view itself can decide (codebehind) which template is used to present the content.

- small: headline with a small thumbnail
- medium: small image with headline
- large: image with headline and some text from article

Alle items are arranged in groups by 5 to 9 items for each group. The groups are presented inside an ItemsControl and each group is presented by a WrapPanel (vertical oriantation).

Lets see that for some rows:

- 2 columns, 6 items

```
lllll  mmmmm
lllll  mmmmm
lllll  mmmmm
lllll
lllll  sssss

lllll  mmmmm
lllll  mmmmm
lllll  mmmmm
lllll
lllll  sssss
```

- 3 columns, 6 items

```
lllll  lllll  mmmmm
lllll  lllll  mmmmm
lllll  lllll  mmmmm
lllll  lllll  
lllll  lllll  lllll
              lllll
mmmmm  mmmmm  lllll
mmmmm  mmmmm  lllll
mmmmm  mmmmm  lllll
```

- 4 columns, 6 items

```
lllll  lllll  lllll  sssss
lllll  lllll  lllll
lllll  lllll  lllll  sssss
lllll  lllll  lllll
lllll  lllll  lllll  sssss
```

- 5 columns, 6 items

```
mmmmm  mmmmm  mmmmm  mmmmm  sssss
mmmmm  mmmmm  mmmmm  mmmmm
mmmmm  mmmmm  mmmmm  mmmmm  sssss
```

So we need three DataTemplates for the content items, some templates for the WrapPanel and some logic inside the view to group the items into rows and the template mangement for the WrapPanel and the items inside.

Here a simple XAML PoC just to test the concept:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="col" TargetType="WrapPanel">
                    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemWidth" Value="80"/>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="content" TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5"/>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="small" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource content}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="medium" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource content}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="large" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource content}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="110"/>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="2col6items" TargetType="WrapPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource col}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="240"/>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="3col6items" TargetType="WrapPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource col}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="4col6items" TargetType="WrapPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource col}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="120"/>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="5col6items" TargetType="WrapPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource col}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
                </Style>


            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <!-- first row -->
            <WrapPanel Style="{StaticResource 5col6items}">
                <Border Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource small}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource small}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <!-- second row -->
            <WrapPanel Style="{StaticResource 4col6items}">
                <Border Style="{StaticResource large}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource large}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource large}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource small}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource small}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource small}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <!-- third row -->
            <WrapPanel Style="{StaticResource 3col6items}">
                <Border Style="{StaticResource large}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource large}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource large}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <!-- fourth row -->
            <WrapPanel Style="{StaticResource 2col6items}">
                <Border Style="{StaticResource large}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource large}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource small}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource small}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

and the lookalike

[image]

## Update

A *very simple* ProofOfConcept with stretching and templating on resize

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsPresenter" SizeChanged="ItemsPresenter_SizeChanged">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="col" TargetType="WrapPanel">
                        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                        <Setter Property="ItemWidth" Value="{Binding ColumnWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="content" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="small" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource content}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="medium" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource content}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="large" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource content}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSalmon"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="110"/>
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="1col6items" TargetType="WrapPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource col}">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="480"/>
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="2col6items" TargetType="WrapPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource col}">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="240"/>
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="3col6items" TargetType="WrapPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource col}">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="4col6items" TargetType="WrapPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource col}">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="120"/>
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="5col6items" TargetType="WrapPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource col}">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
                    </Style>


                </ItemsControl.Resources>
                <!-- first row -->
                <WrapPanel >
                    <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>3</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>4</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>5</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>6</TextBlock>
                </WrapPanel>
                <!-- second row -->
                <WrapPanel >
                    <TextBlock>7</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>8</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>9</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>10</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>11</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>12</TextBlock>
                </WrapPanel>
                <!-- third row -->
                <WrapPanel >
                    <TextBlock>13</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>14</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>15</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>16</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>17</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>18</TextBlock>
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the codebehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent( );
    }

    public int ColumnCount
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue( ColumnCountProperty ); }
        private set { SetValue( ColumnCountProperty, value ); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnCount.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ColumnCount", typeof( int ), typeof( MainWindow ), new PropertyMetadata( 1 ) );

    public double ColumnWidth
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue( ColumnWidthProperty ); }
        private set { SetValue( ColumnWidthProperty, value ); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ColumnWidth", typeof( double ), typeof( MainWindow ), new PropertyMetadata( (double) 100 ) );

    public double ColumnMinWidth
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue( ColumnMinWidthProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue( ColumnMinWidthProperty, value );
            CalculateColumnLayout( );
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnMinWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnMinWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ColumnMinWidth", typeof( double ), typeof( MainWindow ), new PropertyMetadata( (double) 200 ) );

    public double ColumnMaxWidth
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue( ColumnMaxWidthProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue( ColumnMaxWidthProperty, value );
            CalculateColumnLayout( );
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnMaxWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnMaxWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ColumnMaxWidth", typeof( double ), typeof( MainWindow ), new PropertyMetadata( (double) 250 ) );

    private void CalculateColumnLayout()
    {
        int colCount = ColumnCount;
        double totalWidth = ItemsPresenter.ActualWidth;
        double colWidth = totalWidth / colCount;

        while ( colCount > 1 && colWidth < Math.Min( ColumnMinWidth, ColumnMaxWidth ) )
        {
            colCount--;
            colWidth = totalWidth / colCount;
        }

        while ( colCount < 5 && colWidth > Math.Max( ColumnMinWidth, ColumnMaxWidth ) )
        {
            colCount++;
            colWidth = totalWidth / colCount;
        }

        if ( ColumnCount != colCount )
        {
            ColumnCount = colCount;
            StyleItemsPresenterItems( );
        }
        ColumnWidth = colWidth;
    }

    private Dictionary<int, string[]> _styles = new Dictionary<int, string[]>
    {
        [ 1 ] = new string[] { "medium", "medium", "medium", "medium", "medium", "medium" },
        [ 2 ] = new string[] { "large", "medium", "small", "small", "medium", "large" },
        [ 3 ] = new string[] { "large", "medium", "medium", "large", "large", "medium" },
        [ 4 ] = new string[] { "large", "large", "large", "small", "small", "small" },
        [ 5 ] = new string[] { "medium", "medium", "medium", "medium", "small", "small" },
    };


    private void StyleItemsPresenterItems()
    {
        foreach ( var pnl in ItemsPresenter.Items.OfType<WrapPanel>( ) )
        {
            if ( pnl != null )
            {
                pnl.Style = ItemsPresenter.Resources[ $"{ColumnCount}col6items" ] as Style;

                foreach ( var item in pnl.Children.OfType<TextBlock>( ).Zip( _styles[ ColumnCount ], ( border, stylename ) => new { border, stylename } ) )
                {
                    item.border.Style = ItemsPresenter.Resources[ item.stylename ] as Style;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void ItemsPresenter_SizeChanged( object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        CalculateColumnLayout( );
    }
}
```

and finally the result

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to strecht (adjust the size of) the individual items, and thus does not answer the specific question. Or am I wrong?

Comment: But what about virtualization?

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid.itemwidth.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the ItemWidth can be set to Auto.

> The default value of ItemHeight and ItemWidth is not 0, it is
>   Double.NaN. ItemHeight and ItemWidth support the ability to be an
>   unset "Auto" value. Because ItemHeight and ItemWidth are Double
>   values, Double.NaN is used as a special value to represent this "Auto"
>   behavior. The layout system interprets the "Auto" value to generally
>   mean that the object should be sized to the available size in layout,
>   instead of to a specific pixel value.

I don't know if this will result in the behavior you want though. If it doesn't then you might be able to get it by binding the ItemWidth to a property where you calculate the item width based on the width of the grid. It would look something like this:

```
float DynamicItemWidth {
  get {
    int ItemMinimumWidth = 300, margin = 16; //just some guesses
    var gridWidth = ...;

    var numberOfColumns = gridWidth % ItemMinimumWidth;
    var itemWidth = (gridWidth - margin * (numberOfColumns - 1)) / numberOfColumns;

    return itemWidth;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is similar to what I currently use, but I was looking for more elegant solution. I also manually recalculate ItemHeight in the way so the content all fit in height and don't left extra gaps.

Comment: In what way should it be more elegant? It is only a short piece of code and easy to understand. Perhaps abstract it away by creating a subclass of VariableSizedWrapGrid (ie DynamicSizedWrapGrid) and use that instead?

Answer (score 2):

## UWP

As an addition to my previous answer where I show the basic concept here a solution for UWP platform using the `VariableSizedWrapPanel` as mentioned in the question:

The main job is done by

```xml
<local:MyGridView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyGridTemplateSelector}" 
    MinItemWidth="300" MaxItemWidth="600" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemHeight="180" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</local:MyGridView>
```

along with

### MyGridView.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public class MyGridView : GridView
    {
        private int _columnCount = 1;
        private double _itemWidth = 100;

        public double MinItemWidth
        {
            get { return (double) GetValue( MinItemWidthProperty ); }
            set { SetValue( MinItemWidthProperty, value ); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MinItemWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinItemWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register( "MinItemWidth", typeof( double ), typeof( MyGridView ), new PropertyMetadata( 100.0 ) );


        public double MaxItemWidth
        {
            get { return (double) GetValue( MaxItemWidthProperty ); }
            set { SetValue( MaxItemWidthProperty, value ); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MaxItemWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxItemWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register( "MaxItemWidth", typeof( double ), typeof( MyGridView ), new PropertyMetadata( 200.0 ) );


        private long _itemsPanelPropertyChangedToken;

        public MyGridView()
        {
            _itemsPanelPropertyChangedToken = RegisterPropertyChangedCallback( ItemsPanelProperty, ItemsPanelChangedAsync );
        }

        private async void ItemsPanelChangedAsync( DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp )
        {
            UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback( ItemsPanelProperty, _itemsPanelPropertyChangedToken );
            await this.Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync( ItemsPanelChangedCallback );
        }

        private void ItemsPanelChangedCallback( IdleDispatchedHandlerArgs e )
        {
            var wg = ItemsPanelRoot as VariableSizedWrapGrid;
            if (wg != null)
            {
                wg.ItemWidth = _itemWidth;
            }
        }

        protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride( DependencyObject element, object item )
        {
            var itemIndex = this.Items.IndexOf( item );

            element.SetValue( VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, GetRowSpanByColumnCountAndIndex( _columnCount, itemIndex ) );
            element.SetValue( VerticalContentAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Stretch );
            element.SetValue( HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch );
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride( element, item );
        }

        private static readonly Dictionary<int, int[]> _rowSpanLayout = new Dictionary<int, int[]>
        {
            [ 1 ] = new int[] { /* 5 */ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, /* 6 */ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, /* 7 */ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, /* 8 */ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, /* 9 */ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 },
            [ 2 ] = new int[] { /* 5 */ 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, /* 6 */ 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, /* 7 */ 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, /* 8 */ 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, /* 9 */ 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1 },
            [ 3 ] = new int[] { /* 5 */ 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, /* 6 */ 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, /* 7 */ 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, /* 8 */ 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, /* 9 */ 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2 },
            [ 4 ] = new int[] { /* 5 */ 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, /* 6 */ 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, /* 7 */ 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, /* 8 */ 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, /* 9 */ 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 },
            [ 5 ] = new int[] { /* 5 */ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, /* 6 */ 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, /* 7 */ 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, /* 8 */ 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, /* 9 */ 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        };

        private int GetRowSpanByColumnCountAndIndex( int columnCount, int itemIndex )
        {
            return _rowSpanLayout[ columnCount ][ itemIndex % 35 ];
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride( Size availableSize )
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( availableSize );

            int columnCount = _columnCount;
            double availableWidth = availableSize.Width;

            double itemWidth = availableWidth / columnCount;

            while ( columnCount > 1 && itemWidth < Math.Min( MinItemWidth, MaxItemWidth ) )
            {
                columnCount--;
                itemWidth = availableWidth / columnCount;
            }

            while ( columnCount < 5 && itemWidth > Math.Max( MinItemWidth, MaxItemWidth ) )
            {
                columnCount++;
                itemWidth = availableWidth / columnCount;
            }

            var wg = this.ItemsPanelRoot as VariableSizedWrapGrid;

            _itemWidth = itemWidth;
            if ( _columnCount != columnCount )
            {
                _columnCount = columnCount;
                if ( wg != null )
                {
                    Update( );
                }
            }

            if ( wg != null )
            {
                wg.ItemWidth = itemWidth;
            }

            return base.MeasureOverride( availableSize );
        }

        // refresh the variablesizedwrapgrid layout
        private void Update()
        {
            if ( !( this.ItemsPanelRoot is VariableSizedWrapGrid ) )
                throw new ArgumentException( "ItemsPanel is not VariableSizedWrapGrid" );

            int itemIndex = 0;
            foreach ( var container in this.ItemsPanelRoot.Children.Cast<GridViewItem>( ) )
            {
                int rowSpan = GetRowSpanByColumnCountAndIndex( _columnCount, itemIndex );
                VariableSizedWrapGrid.SetRowSpan( container, rowSpan );
                itemIndex++;
            }

            this.ItemsPanelRoot.InvalidateMeasure( );
        }
    }
}
```

and

### MyGridViewTemplateSelector.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public class MyGridViewTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate Small { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate Medium { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate Large { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore( object item, DependencyObject container )
        {
            var rowSpan = container.GetValue( VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty );

            int index;
            try
            {
                dynamic model = item;
                index = model.Index;
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                index = -1;
            }
            long token = 0;

            DependencyPropertyChangedCallback lambda = ( sender, dp ) =>
            {
                container.UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback( VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, token );

                var cp = (ContentControl) container;
                cp.ContentTemplateSelector = null;
                cp.ContentTemplateSelector = this;
            };

            token = container.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback( VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, lambda );

            switch ( rowSpan )
            {
                case 1:
                    return Small;
                case 2:
                    return Medium;
                case 3:
                    return Large;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException( );
            }
        }

        private void Foo( DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException( );
        }
    }
}
```

To complete here the other files

### MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Small">
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.75"/>
                    </StackPanel.Background>

                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" Margin="10">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Index}"/>. <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Small" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Medium">
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.75"/>
                    </StackPanel.Background>

                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" Margin="10">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Index}"/>. <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Medium" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Large">
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.75"/>
                    </StackPanel.Background>

                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" Margin="10">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Index}"/>. <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Large" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
        <local:MyGridViewTemplateSelector x:Key="MyGridTemplateSelector"
                                          Small="{StaticResource Small}"
                                          Medium="{StaticResource Medium}"
                                          Large="{StaticResource Large}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- top left section -->

        <Border Background="#D13438">

        </Border>

        <!-- top bar -->

        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Padding="5" Background="#F2F2F2">
            <TextBlock Text="MenuBar" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>

        <!-- left bar -->

        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="48" Background="#2B2B2B">

        </Border>

        <!-- content -->

        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="#E6E6E6">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Padding="5" Background="#F2F2F2">
                    <TextBlock Text="SectionBar" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                    <Border Margin="7,7,10,7">

                        <!-- the wrapped news items -->

                        <local:MyGridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyGridTemplateSelector}" MinItemWidth="300" MaxItemWidth="600" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemHeight="180" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        </local:MyGridView>

                    </Border>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

### MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Reflection;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent( );

            // just some sample data

            var colors = typeof( Colors )
                .GetRuntimeProperties( )
                .Take( 140 )
                .Select( ( x, index ) => new
                {
                    Color = (Color) x.GetValue( null ),
                    Name = x.Name,
                    Index = index,
                } );
            this.DataContext = colors;
        }

    }
}
```

If you will ever think "I know that from somewhere" you should have a look at [Jerry Nixon's blog](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html) :o)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the best way to achieve the desired result is to write custom panel and use it as `ItemPanel` in `GridView` (or `ListView`).

**This is how it looks:**
[image]

**This control allow you to achieve the following:**

- All blocks on the single row has the same width and height.
- Number of columns and columns width calculated automatically based on `ItemMinWidth` property (default is 300px).
- No gap on the right side of the `GridView`
- Cell height calculated on the fly based on the content (so, if the content changed - for example if user changed the font size in the app, it automatically recalculated).
- Every row has different (**sic!**) height (not one for the whole panel like in `VariableSizedWrapGrid`)
- You can also set `MaxColumnCount` property if you want to limit number of columns (for example if set to 4, number of columns may be 1, 2, 3 or 4).

**My custom panel (I called it `SmartPanel`, sorry for this):**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

class SmartPanel : Panel
        {
            int _colCount;
            double _cellWidth;
            double[] _cellHeights;


            public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemMinWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemMinWidth", typeof(double), typeof(SmartPanel), new PropertyMetadata(300D));
            public double ItemMinWidth
            {
                get { return (double)GetValue(ItemMinWidthProperty); }
            }


            public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxColumnCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaxColumnCount", typeof(int), typeof(SmartPanel), new PropertyMetadata(10));
            public int MaxColumnCount
            {
                get { return (int)GetValue(MaxColumnCountProperty); }
                set { SetValue(MaxColumnCountProperty, value); }
            }


            protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
            {
                _colCount = (int)(availableSize.Width / ItemMinWidth);
                if (_colCount > MaxColumnCount) _colCount = MaxColumnCount;

                _cellWidth = (int)(availableSize.Width / _colCount);

                var rowCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)Children.Count / _colCount);

                _cellHeights = new double[rowCount];

                var y = 0;
                var x = 0;
                foreach (UIElement child in Children)
                {
                    child.Measure(new Size(_cellWidth, double.PositiveInfinity));
                    _cellHeights[y] = Math.Max(_cellHeights[y], child.DesiredSize.Height);

                    x++;
                    if (x >= _colCount)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y++;
                    }
                }

                y = 0;
                x = 0;
                foreach (UIElement child in Children)
                {
                    child.Measure(new Size(_cellWidth, _cellHeights[y]));

                    x++;
                    if (x >= _colCount)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y++;
                    }
                }

                if (double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Height))
                {
                    availableSize.Height = _cellHeights.Sum();
                }

                return availableSize;
            }



            protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
            {
                double x = 0;
                double y = 0;
                int colNum = 0;
                int rowNum = 0;
                foreach (UIElement child in Children)
                {

                    child.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, _cellWidth, _cellHeights[rowNum]));
                    //child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(x, y), child.DesiredSize));
                    x += _cellWidth;
                    colNum++;

                    if (colNum >= _colCount)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y += _cellHeights[rowNum];
                        colNum = 0;
                        rowNum++;
                    }
                }
                return finalSize;
            }


        }
```

**Usage:**

```
<GridView x:Name="MainGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20,0,20"
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}"
                                       ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" 
                                       >
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ctl:SmartPanel Margin="10,0,10,0" MaxColumnCount="4" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>

</GridView>
```